# Sequelize defining tables pluralized when using sync

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I've written migrations to define my tables in a seperate service. Im then using a node.js service to run sequelize where i'm defining my models like this:

```
import Sequelize from "sequelize";
import sequelize from "../config/sequelize";

export const MasterPlaylist = sequelize.define("Master_playlist", {
  id: { type: Sequelize.STRING, primaryKey: true },
  updated_at: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE,
    defaultValue: new Date(),
    allowNull: false,
  },
});
```

Im then importing this and calling it like so:

```
import Sequelize from "sequelize";
import sequelize from "./config/sequelize";
import { Label } from "./models/Label";

async function run(){
   await sequelize.sync();
   const label = await Label.findOne();
   console.log("done", label);
}

run()
```

Have simplified things slightly here, but this is whats being run.
When i run this it creates new tables but pluralised so i end up with the correctly named tables as inserted by the migrations and then pluralised copies.

For example for this table i end up with 'Master_playlists'

Anyone got an idea whats happening here?

here is my config file:

```
import Sequelize from "sequelize";

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  process.env.DB,
  process.env.USERNAME,
  process.env.PASSWORD,
  {
    host: process.env.HOST,
    dialect: "postgres",
  }
);

async function run() {
  await sequelize.authenticate();
}

run();
export default sequelize;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what the issue is, but sequelize uses [inflection](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inflection) to pluralize table names.

> By default, when the table name is not given, Sequelize automatically pluralizes the model name and uses that as the table name. This pluralization is done under the hood by a library called inflection, so that irregular plurals (such as person -> people) are computed correctly.

You can control the table names directly using `freezeTableName: true` which will keep the table name the same as model name:

```
sequelize.define('User', {
  // ... (attributes)
}, {
  freezeTableName: true
});
```

or specify the table name explicitly:

```
sequelize.define('User', {
  // ... (attributes)
}, {
  tableName: 'users'
});
```